# Cursor stuck in (Box select?) Mode

Tags: modeling

I don't have any idea what's going on https://gyazo.com/41ae3432ea76837f06e3ecfb288efd00

I can click on some things but not anything like file (to save my project) or tick and boxes. What's wrong?

Comment: What OS are you working on? I've found that on XFCE (Dekstop environment for Linux) when you do some crazy stuff with your cursor it sometimes gets stuck just like your recorded. Minimizing everything usually gets it back to normal. Otherwise try to press Escape or box select again etc. when it happens.

Comment: Windows 10. Pressing escape worked, thanks man!